# Chrome Dev Tools Mobile two finger swipe

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently developing a store finder and in my research I came across this site:

https://www.esprit.com/mobile/storefinder

I was wondering if there is a way to simulate a two finger swipe behavior in dev tools for moving around the map?

What I tried already:

- double click and drag
- shift and click+drag

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for a way to pan the (Google) map when simulating a touch device in the dev tools on the app I'm working on, since since click + drag brings up the "Use two fingers to move the map" message.  It seems the arrow keys will pan the map in this case - I checked and it doesn't seem to work with the app you linked above, but hopefully this will help someone else.